# Jupyter Notebook Latex Conversion Fails: Escaped $ and other symbols?

Tags: conversion

Trying to convert an R notebook into a (download as) pdf; the LateX conversion fails with this part of the error seemingly relevant:

```
! LaTeX Error: \mathbf allowed only in math mode.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.284 Show that \$ (\mathbf A
                              \mathbf B)\^{}T = \mathbf B\^{}T
? 
! Emergency stop.
```

The Markdown cell in question looks like so:

```
## Question 1
Show that 
$ (\mathbf A \mathbf B)^T =  \mathbf B^T \mathbf A^T$ for matrices $\mathbf A \in \mathbb R^{m \times n}$ and $\mathbf B \in \mathbb R^{n \times l}$ by writing componentwise.
```

It appears as though between the Markdown cell and LateX input, the `$` sign was escaped, and LateX now doesn't recognize it. In fact, it also looks like other symbols, like the caret `^`, are being escaped, too.

Am using Windows 8, Chrome version 58.0.3029.81, Jupyter version 4.2.0, Jupyter Notebook version 4.2.3.

How can I correct this?

Comment: Apparently, the converter considers an isolated `$` as something that should become `\$`, as you can see in the error message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some inspection, I noticed that the problem was the space after the `$` sign - this:

```
$ (\mathbf A \mathbf B)^T =  \mathbf B^T \mathbf A^T$
```

needs to be like so:

```
$(\mathbf A \mathbf B)^T =  \mathbf B^T \mathbf A^T$
```

and so on. It seems that MathJax has no problem with it, but `nbconvert` needs this format.